# AWS Kinesis Video Streams for real time viewing and archived viewing

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, amazon-kinesis

I was hoping to get some advice on a problem I am having with my understanding of AWS kinesis Video Streaming, integrated with my react app.

I have read all of the documentation on the AWS KVS and I am still none the wiser and I feel I need a little direction in order to know how the technologies fit together.

I want to plug aws KVS into my react app.

The react app has a springboot API for other functionality. (This may or may not be relevant, discussed more explicitly later in the question)

I know that there is a [Java producer SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-sdk-javaapi.html) from which I can call the kvs putMedia API, provide an mkv video file and then view the video in the aws kvs video stream console. This works fine (to test the API but does not provide the functionality I need), so in order to stream live video from a webcam I have been looking at the [Javascrivpt WebRTC SDK example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/kvswebrtc-sdk-js.html) and the [KVS WebRTC Test Page](https://awslabs.github.io/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js/examples/index.html)

Can someone please explain, if I use the javascript WebRTC SDK on the client and establish a signalling channel and necessary programming for viewer(s) and master, do I need to use the putMedia API specifying the video stream, or is this all managed through the client and the signalling channel? Can I forget about the Java producer SDK and not include any KVS requirements in the spring boot part of my application??

And, what is the best way to ensure that this video can be viewed in real time but also retrospectively. I initially thought to record the video stream and push it to an S3 bucket, but is this possible in this use case? I know the [getMedia](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/API_dataplane_GetMedia.html) API or [GetHLSStreamingSessionURL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/API_reader_GetHLSStreamingSessionURL.html) API can be called on a video stream to view the video, but is this also the case in the scenario of just a signalling channel?? Again, I recognise the limitations to my understanding of the architecture.

Thanks

Comment: How did it go with it?, from my understanding it seems the only way with the SDK to put media is using Java, C or C++ the other SDK only for consume, that is extremely disappointing. I saw in python but havent been able to work it out is using canonical signature to do an API, but this has to be done in a loop to send the little chunks, let us know if you find a way, I am hopping i am wrong and there is an easy way